# Qual código uso pra criar uma classe Validacao no AndroidStudio?

Tags: java, android-studio

Estou querendo criar uma classe pra verificar se os 2 campos `EditText` estão preenchidos, chamado `Validacao`. Queria chamar tipo:

```
if (Validacao(TextoA, TextoB) == true) {
    executa código;
```

Não estou sabendo como fica o código da classe `Validacao`. É preciso ter um construtor `Validacao()`? Como ficaria o código?

```
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Validacao {
    private boolean x = true;
    private boolean y = true;
    private boolean z = true;
    private boolean a = false;

    public Validacao(EditText textA, EditText textB) {
        // Valida para ter todos os 2 campos preenchidos
        if ((textA.getText().toString().isEmpty()) && (textB.getText().toString().isEmpty())) {
            z = false;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Informe os números." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        } else if (textA.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            x = false;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Informe o primeiro número." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        } else if (textB.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            y = false;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Informe o segundo número." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
    if (x && y && z)
        a = true;
    return a;
}
```

Comment: if(NomeDaVariavel.getText().toString().equals(" ")){ Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Por favor preencher o texto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); Não sei se essa era a dúvida, mas pra fazer a validação se o texto não está nulo é assim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando definido uma função com o mesmo nome da classe, essa função será a função construtora dessa classe, e deve ser invocada através do operador `new`

Como você está criando uma classe de validação, sugiro que use funções estáticas e a lógica de verificar quantas variáveis são válidas seja feita aonde esses métodos sejam chamados

Por exemplo:

```
public class Validacao {
    public Validacao() {  }

    public static boolean isValid(EditText et, String msg, Context context) {
        if (et.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Para usar:

```
if (Validacao.isValid(x, "Informe o primeiro número", getApplicationContext()) && Validacao.isValid(y, , "Informe o segundo número", getApplicationContext()) && Validacao.isValid(z, "Informe o terceiro número", getApplicationContext())) {
    // Faz alguma coisa
}
```

Você também pode criar uma função personalizada pra cada variável

Comment: Não tá dando certo. Seria public static **boolean** isValid(EditText et, String msg) { ... }? Mesmo assim, dá erro na classe Validacao, isso no AndroidStudio.

Comment: Sim, faltou definir o tipo, faz um tempo que não mecho com java, esqueci de colocar, qual o erro que aparece? Acredito que o problema seja esse `this`, tente usar `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: @JoãoRicardo editei a pergunta, verifique se atende o que precisa

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme, mais já consegui rodar o exemplo